# Bend plane with panorama image

Tags: image

**Main question**

I have large panorama images (not necessarily a full circle of 360°) with let's say 23000x3600px and I want to include the image to the scene, bend it to a circle (or almost circle in case it is less than 360°) and fly around it in a short movie sequence.

I imported the images as textures using the images to planes addon.

**Minor problem (already solved in an acceptable way)**

The first problem I encountered is that such a large image can't be handeled correctly which seems to be a problem of RAM according to my research. This can be solved by reducing the enormous size of the images to something more suitable. But maybe I oversee something and there is still an option for very large images.

**Main problem**

How to bend the planes with the images to something like a circle or sector of a circle? This should unwarp the panorama image roughly; it does not have to be exact.

I tried it with loop cut -> proportional editing -> circle. But the result is half of a circle at maximum. Is there an easy way to bend the plane? Using a cylinder and adding the texture has not worked on a first try, but maybe I have to experiment with this.

**Background**

I have a map of a holiday trip and want to fly over it showing images alongside the visited cities. Some of the images are of normal format, some of panorama format. The latter should be processed as described.

Comment: I have a question: How much RAM do you currently have? And are you using a desktop, a laptop or an AIO?

Comment: I use a desktop pc with 16GB (without blender compatible graphic card). Should be ok imo. I think reducing the size of the images is a good idea anyway especially as long as the result is not rendered with a similar resolution as the images itself (2k x 1k in Blender vs. 5k x 3k for the images at the moment). The second problem still persists.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Why not use your image as a world environment texture instead?

Comment: I have more panorama images. It's like flying over a map (a plane with a map of the country of a holiday trip). Alongside the cities the images should be shown (panorama and non-panorama). The question is how to do that for a panorama. I want it in a way that it is unwarped by projecting it on a (sector of a) circle. The question is separated in two parts, but I think it is still one question, especially with the first part already solved in an acceptable way. Nevertheless, if it should be unclear, the second part is the one I'm asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I use the Curve Modifier.
I subdivided the plane using Cut and Slide with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
I created a NurbsPath cuverd the desired shape.
So I used the Curve modifier.
The plane just fits half the curve, then you shall move and scale de plane to envolve the entire curve as you wish. Good luck.[image]

Comment: Your solution works pretty well, thank you for that! As further comment for to the approach: It is a bit difficile to scale both, the curve and the plane correctly which both have a significant influence on the result. But with some experience it can be done quickly.